# The action of a subgroup of the torsion group of elliptic curves on integral points?

Tags: finite-groups, elliptic-curves, group-actions, torsion

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve given in long Weierstraß form with all coefficients $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_6 \in \mathbb{Z}$. It is known that the rational points $E(\mathbb{Q})$ form a group which has a finite torsion subgroup $T$.

1. Question:

What is known about the action of the following subgroup $\hat{T} \le T$ on the integral points $E(\mathbb{Z})$:

$$\hat{T} := \{ t \in T | t + E(\mathbb{Z}) \subset E(\mathbb{Z}) \}$$

?

I have found one elliptic curve where this $\hat{T}$ is not the trivial group:

https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/210/e/6

For this curve:

$$T := \left[\left(0 : 1 : 0\right), \left(4 : 58 : 1\right), \left(64 : 418 : 1\right), \left(-26 : 148 : 1\right), \left(28 : -14 : 1\right), \left(-26 : -122 : 1\right), \left(64 : -482 : 1\right), \left(4 : -62 : 1\right), \left(-36 : 18 : 1\right), \left(34 : -122 : 1\right), \left(-8 : -122 : 1\right), \left(244 : -3902 : 1\right), \left(\frac{31}{4} : -\frac{31}{8} : 1\right), \left(244 : 3658 : 1\right), \left(-8 : 130 : 1\right), \left(34 : 88 : 1\right)\right]
$$

and

$$\hat{T}:= \left[\left(0 : 1 : 0\right), \left(\frac{31}{4} : -\frac{31}{8} : 1\right)\right]$$

I must admit, that in most cases where I looked at numerical examples, we had $\hat{T} = 1$.

2. Question: Are there examples of elliptic curves with $1 < \hat{T} = T$?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Probably(?) you want to specify that you're taking a minimal Weierstrass equation. For question 2, there are lots of (trivial) example, namely any curve of rank 0 with non-trivial torsion subgroup!  It's interesting that the example that you found has the largest possible torsion subgroup.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer question 1. on my own as good as I can:

Consider two cases:

1.) $\hat{T} \cap E(\mathbb{Z}) \neq \emptyset$
Let $Q$ be an element in this intersection. Then $-Q \in \hat{T}$ and adding this to $Q \in E(\mathbb{Z})$ we get by hypothesis on $\hat{T}$ a point in $E(\mathbb{Z})$, so

$$ O = (-Q) + Q \in E(\mathbb{Z})$$

which is a contradiction, to SAGEMATHs definition of integral points $E(\mathbb{Z})$.
So this case can not happen.

2.) $\hat{T} \cap E(\mathbb{Z}) = \emptyset$

Then by [Nagel-Lutz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem), either $\hat{T}=1$ or each $Q \in \hat{T}$ is of the form $Q=(\frac{m}{4},\frac{n}{8},1)$ and has $\operatorname{ord}(Q)=2$. This means in the latter case that $\hat{T} = C_2 \times \ldots \times C_2$ which leaves by a theorem of [Mazur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_conjecture#Elliptic_curves$$) only the cases $C_2,C_2 \times C_2$ open.

All in all, we get three possible cases:

$$\hat{T} = 1, C_2, C_2 \times C_2$$

of which I have seen examples for the first two. Is there an example for $\hat{T} = C_2 \times C_2$?

Answer (score 2):

The subgroup $\hat T$ cannot contain any integral points because each $t \in \hat T$ is the $t$-translate of the origin which is not an integral point.
Therefore by Nagell-Lutz $\hat T$ is either trivial or has exponent $2$, and I think it's known that there can be at most one non-integral torsion point $t \neq 0$, so $\hat T$ must have order $2$.

As **Joe Silverman** notes in a comment, if the curve has rank zero then automatically $t \in \hat T$ so $\hat T$ is nontrivial.  If moreover $t$ is the only nontrivial torsion point then $\hat T = T$.  Such examples are now easy to find in the LMFDB by asking for rank 0, torsion Z/2Z, and zero integral points; and there are plentiful examples starting from the curves 14.a1, 15.a1, 15.a3, ...

But this may not be deemed interesting because there are no integral points to permute.  If there *are* integral points then they must come in sets of 4.  The first example of torsion Z/2Z and four integral points is the curve [274.b2](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/274/b/2): $y^2 + xy = x^3 - x^2 + 8x - 6$, with 2-torsion point $t : (x,y) = (3/4,-3/8)$ and pairs of integral points at $x=1$ and $x=35$ that are switched by translation by $t$.  The [next example](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/285/b/1)
(285.b1) works too.

Comment: (the first curve with |T|=2 and 8 integral points works too: https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/102/a/2)